# Failing to edit and re-order Path on Catalina

Tags: python, bash, terminal, path, macos-catalina

I’m on osX Catalina. When in the Terminal I’m doing an `echo $PATH`, here is the output :

```
/Users/Nicolas/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/Nicolas/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/Nicolas/.poetry/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

I realized that I need to reorder the PATH because when I’m trying to create a virtual environment with `pipenv install requests` the output is `command not found: pipenv` despite having it installed.

After reading posts and tutorials, here is what I’m doing to (try to) correct the issue :

1. I move into the home directory in the terminal
2. A create a .zsh file with the command : `nano .zsh`
3. I add the following :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Nicolas/.local/bin
```

The first export is to reorder the PATH, the second line is an answer to the following warning that I had when installing pipenv :

```
 WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in ‘/Users/Nicolas/.local/bin’ which is not on PATH.
```

Then I save the file, exit, reboot the computer. When I’m running the `echo $PATH` again, nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try re-installing with `Homebrew`

```
brew uninstall pipenv
brew install pipenv

pipenv install requests
```